Could not boot AlmaLinux when restart the os
I tried to reboot my alama linux 9, then it couldn't boot. The following are some of the error snapshots.


I booted into single mode and moved snap related systemd files, but it's the similar errors which could not boot.
I also tried lvm lvscan, lvm lvchange -ay and xfs_repair. But none of them worked.


see 'systemctl status var-lib-snapd-snap-bare-5.mount' for details.

@GregAskew But I can't start normally, the /proc is not mounted, the command couldn't run.
